# How to test a maven service which needs another service in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, testing, mocking

I have searched two days for an answer. I tried @Mock, @InjectMock and @Spy with different additional things, but nothing worked how it was described in tutorials. Many Questions I found dealt with a Problem in Angular, this is my first spring-boot/maven project and have never worked with Angular.

I have a Basic Service for some values I want to be able to change only there but need them in multiple other services. I have written a shortened example of the base structure I want to test and I included the workaround I found for the moment, but would love to know how experienced programmers would go about this.

I have my configuration Service:

```
@Service
public class ConfigService {
    private final int initialLength = 4;

    public int getInitialLength() {
        return initialLength;
    }

    public double getInitialSquared() {
        return Math.pow(4,2);
    }    
}
```

And another Service using it:

```
@Service
public class OtherService {

    @Autowired
    ConfigService configService;

    // How I surpassed it for now is overloading and only testing the second function
    String printLine() {
        return printLine(configService.getInitialLength());
    }

    String printLine(int length) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < configService.getInitialLength(); i++) {
            output.append("-");
        }
        return output.toString();
    }

}
```

And my Test for now:

```
class OtherServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    OtherService otherService = new OtherService();

    @Test
    void printLine() {
        AssertEquals("----", OtherService.printLine(4));
    }
}
```

Comment: '@injectMocks' or '@InjectMocks' (capital i)?

Comment: capital I of course, sorry misspelled by typing a reduced example in here. This part works in my program, only if I try to test 'printLine()' witout a given number I get a NullPointerException.

Comment: Because your input parameter of String printLine method  should have some length. either you can put a check for length not less than one

Comment: You need to add a mock in your `OtherServiceTest` for `ConfigService` and also remove the usage of `new OtherService();` cause this is handled by Mockito...also you have to add either `@runWith(Mockito..)` (I can't exactly remember the part for JUnit4  or an `@ExtendsWith(MocktoExtension.class)`(JUnit Jupiter)

Comment: Rewrite your `OtherService` so that it takes `initialLength` as a constructor parameter.

Comment: @khmarbaise I tried to Mock the Configservice using '@Mock', '@Spy' and '@InjectMock' but it never worked. If I nemove the 'New Configservice' I end up with a NullPointerException. I'll look up '@runWith/@ExtendsWith' now, thanks for pointing me in a direction :)